# Accidentally disabled error squiggles in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I accidentally disabled error squiggles on Visual Studio Code. I was programming and got an error so I clicked on the light bulb to see what the error was, but accidentally clicked on "Disable error squiggles." Just wondering if there was a way to unhide/enable them again. Thanks

Comment: Look into `.vscode/settings.json` and see if any of the settings there indicate something to this effect. You can also look into your global settings. To get there: `Ctrl+,`, then click the `{}` to open in json. The json file shows only altered settings, whereas the nice GUI shows all settings.

Comment: Hello I reviewed you comment and edited my answer let me know if it helps

Comment: @EdwardWong What language were you working in when you disabled error highlighting? I know that, for example, the VSCode C++ extension has a dedicated setting for error highlighting.

Comment: For javascript the setting would be `javascript.validate.enable`.  Look for a similar setting contributed by a `C++` extesnion.

Comment: @EdwardWong You can list the specific setting you changed in an answer to your own question :-). Feel free to integrate my comment into your answer.

Comment: @Justin this doesn't help for my similar case. (debian testing, vscode v1.36.1) Looks like these lines should be added somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

[Click Right Click in your editor window and select for 'Command Pallet' option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlQ5c.png)

OR press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and search for the option 'Enable Error Squiggle' and just click on it.
[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ep3K.png)
That's it!
If you want to Disable Red Wavy underlines showed after syntax error, just Follow the above procedure and search for 'Disable Error Squiggle' and click on it.

Answer (score 6):

Go to "Extensions" in the sidebar, after that go to your extension for C / C ++, click on manage, then click on extension settings. In the search box, add the term "error" right after what is already written there. It has three tabs, "User", "Workspace", "Your_Folder", the User being the one being viewed. Go to "Error Squiggles" and select "EnabledIflncludesResolve". Then, check if in the "Workspace" tab and folder "EnabledIflncludesResolve" is also selected. [I took a print of my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6xBh.png) In my case I use Microsoft's C / C ++ extension (ms-vscode.cpptools).

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was able to go into VS Code and hit the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and easily type "Squiggle" here I got the option to both enable or disable the errors. This makes it easy to switch back and forth between the two if need be.

Answer (score 0):

just install the C/C++ extension again and reload

Answer (score 0):

1. Just go to settings.
2. Search `C_cpp: Error Squiggles` .
3. There you would find your setting which you are looking for.
4. `EnabledIfIncludesResolve` is the default one.